# generate unique key for std::map

Tags: c++

I have a map with a string as the key and stores lambdas.

I've so far tried

```
std::map <int, auto> callbackMap
```

And put a lambda where there isn't one with the same number already. Is this possible ? I keep getting errors saying functions can't have auto as constructors.

Comment: `1`, `2`, `3`, etc are all unique keys. Do they help you? If not, why? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: a std::map only accepts one value for every key, so just start at `0` and increase ?

Comment: your question is not clear. I suggest you to reformulate it before you get downvotes...

Comment: I am trying to store Callbacks in a map, for later use. I am using a scripting engine, the script is given the id of a callback (As it dosn't support being given lambdas directly) it then uses to pass a message back to the native code to run :)

Comment: I don't understand what it has to do with unique keys. Just use `std::map<int, std::function<R(/*...*/)>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `auto` is just a compile time "feature" that converts the type you need to a very defined type! You are maybe confusing it with a "variant" type... it doesn't work this way.

```
auto X = 3;
```

It doesn't mean `X` is a "variant". It's like the **compiler** converts it to:

```
int X = 3;
```

So, notice that `X` has a very defined type.

You CAN store functions (*lambda is the operator*) in your map, no problem. But with your `std::function<...>` very defined. Example:

```
std::map< int, std::function< int( int ) > > callbackMap;
callbackMap[ 0 ] = std::function< int( int ) >( [] ( int a ) { return a + 1; } );
callbackMap[ 1 ] = std::function< int( int ) >( [] ( int a ) { return a - 1; } );
callbackMap[ 2 ] = std::function< int( int ) >( [] ( int a ) { return a * 2; } );
callbackMap[ 3 ] = std::function< int( int ) >( [] ( int a ) { return a / 2; } );
```

Notice that you still need to know the signature of your functions... (here in my example `int( int a )`, but you can define of course the way you want).

If you decide to store "pointers to functions" you will have the same problem. You have to know the signature! Nothing different.

Comment: IS there a way to store a generic lambda, my orginal solution was to have a static member for every lambda but I feels very wrong.

Comment: You can always try `void*` but you obviously need to manage your own memory that way.  Unless all the lambdas have the same calling convention, both arguments in and arguments out.  Then you can use `std::function<>` as this answer originally said.

Comment: "IS there a way to store a generic lambda?" I edited the answer, please read it over again. I hope it helps you!

Comment: I suggest you to REtitle your question to: "Can I use "auto" as a type in a std::map template?" or something similiar. This is your real question. Just a suggestion. Downvotes will come for this title.

Comment: std::map does not have method push_back()

Comment: @Slava, oops, sorry! I confused with std::vector<>... fixed! Thanks! ;-)